# Функция Animate() -- объединяет Смещение, Размеры, Непрозрачность, Вращение

Tags: javascript, css3, объединение

**[BOUNCE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540091/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-bounce)**

Здесь подключена функция:

```
        function Animate(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,k) {
    var l="#"+a,
        f={};
""!=b&&(f.left=b);
""!=c&&(f.top=c);
""!=d&&(f.width=d);
""!=e&&(f.height=e);
""!=g&&(f.opacity=g/100);
0==a.indexOf("wb_")&&(a="#"+a.substring(3),$(a).stop().animate(f,h));
""!=k&&(f.rotate=k);
$(l).stop().animate(f,h)
}
```

обращение к ней:

```
`Animate('Shape', '400', '', '', '', '', 3000, '')`
```

-- она отвечает за горизонтальное перемещение.  В теме **[BOUNCE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540091/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-bounce)** видна ее работа.
Аргументы:

a=Shape -- объект,

b=left:400 -- смещение  от края, px,

с=top: ... px от верха,

d=width: ... px объекта,

e=height: ... px объекта,

g=opacity: ... - непрозрачность в %,

h=3000 -- время в ms.

k=rotate: ... deg -- вращение по Z;

l= #Shape  -- ID объекта,

f={}  -- ???

indexOf("wb_") -- это начало имени , там есть ID= Shape, и ID= wb_Shape внешний для него. Наверное, для разделения анимаций.

Время h=3000 там жестоко присваивается. Не понятно как.

В конце стояли еще 2 текстовых параметра, **;return false;**  судя по смыслу, и без них все прекрасно работает

Просьба как то ее разложить в понятный вид, понять ее аргументы.

Не просто так интересуюсь. Как на место **'400'** засунуть ширину доступного окна ?
Скорее всего это параметр **document.documentElement.scrollWidth** и отнять от нее значение CSS-переменной ?

```
:root {--wide: 160px;
       --cat_left: 0 px}

let root = document.querySelector(":root");
root.style.setProperty("cat_left", document.documentElement.scrollWidth - var(--wide));
```

Здесь я не знаю, как от document.documentElement.scrollWidth отнять CSS-переменную  **--wide**.

```
 `Animate('Shape', cat_left, '', '', '', '', 3000, '')` --- будет работать  ? :)
```

Comment: Исправьте ваш заголовок.

Comment: Заголовок должен содержать краткое изложение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Получаем ширину доступного окна (ширину экрана)
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

// Получаем значение CSS-переменной --wide
const catWidthValue = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--wide').trim();

// Преобразуем catWidthValue в число, предполагая, что оно задано в пикселях
const catWidthInPixels = parseFloat(catWidthValue);

// Рассчитываем разницу между шириной окна и шириной "кота"
const difference = windowWidth - catWidthInPixels;

// Вызываем функцию Animate, передавая разницу как аргумент для b (горизонтального смещения)
Animate('Shape', difference + 'px', '', '', '', '', 3000, '');
```

Теперь Animate будет использовать разницу между шириной окна и шириной "кота" для горизонтального смещения b.

Comment: Дмитрий я добавил Ваш второй ответ. Смотрите, но уже лучше ! Ошибок нет, уже хорошо. 
по логике функция не требует 'px'  (или сама подставляет).
 Еще хорошо, что 400 работает и без кавычек.  Как добить функцию ?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста подробнее что необходимо изменить в самой функции?

Comment: получается там 2 функции onmouseenter="Animate()" и onclick="Animate()" . Вторая показывает, что сама функция живая, мы ее еще не испортили :).  Кот прыгает  по left: 0 , как ему сделать left: окно - ширина ? Без translateX(...)  :)
Смотреть здесь Ваш вариант  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540091/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-bounce

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы кот  прыгал из левого края экрана в правый края экрана без использования translateX, вы можете использовать CSS-анимацию и ключевые кадры (@keyframes)

Comment: Нет, мне надо через эту функцию, чтобь понять , как с ней работать . 
Если на место  difference + 'px' поставить 400, кот будет прыгать, но не до стенки.

Comment: Все, Дмитрий , спасибо !!! . Моя ошибка -- я там придумал лишних функций CSS. Фукнция CSS  не --catWidth  , а --Wide.  А --catWidth я предполагал для JS   :)  самое место объявлять ее в :root {}  :)

Comment: Отлично, я рад что у Вас получилось разобраться с ошибками в коде и все работает как следует!

Comment: Дмитрий, я исправил косяк в чужой функции ! Все линейные размеры  и перемещения понимаются из без "px", а последний аргумент требует 'deg' ! Надо найти авторов, пусть поблагодарят меня.

Comment: Хорошо было бы добавить на этой странице рабочий код этой функции, так как у кого то может возникнуть такая же проблема и здесь можно будет в последующем найти ее решение

Comment: ссылка полную версию функции дана здесь же, выше -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1541058/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-animate-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1541114?noredirect=1#comment2772025_1541114

Comment: Там подключена полная версия библиотеки. У меня подозрение , что она требует полной библиотеки. Возможно, отсылки stop() ,  rotate()  -- именно туда.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы от document.documentElement.scrollWidth отнять CSS-переменную --wide, вам следует сначала получить значение переменной --wide, а затем вычесть его из ширины document.documentElement.scrollWidth. Вот как это можно сделать:

```
// Получите значение переменной --wide
const wideValue = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--wide').trim();

// Преобразуйте значение в число (уберите "px" и преобразуйте в число)
const wideNumber = parseFloat(wideValue);

// Вычтите wideNumber из ширины document.documentElement.scrollWidth
const result = document.documentElement.scrollWidth - wideNumber;

// Установите результат в переменную cat_left
root.style.setProperty("--cat_left", result + "px");
```

В этом коде мы сначала получаем значение --wide и преобразуем его в число, затем вычитаем это число из document.documentElement.scrollWidth. Результат записываем обратно в переменную --cat_left с добавлением "px". Теперь значение --cat_left будет равно разнице между шириной окна и значением --wide.

Comment: Дмитрий, Спасибо, что хотя бы дочитали до конца. Если Вы смотрели ту тему BOUNCE, я понял как применить единицу hv.   Кот отлично прыгает четко в границах снипета.  Но там проще, там translateY() -- это СSS. И никаких стыковок с JS. Я пробую в той теме BOUNCE , сделать тоже самое с шириной перемещения, которую надо всунуть в адский JS. Я думаю, Вы все уже рассказали, надо выбрать подходящий вариант . Спасибо. Кажется, я понял, что этот IS надо вообще удалить. Но доделаю для опыта. :)

Comment: Рад был помочь Вам в решении Вашего вопроса!

Comment: Протестируйте код, если выдаст ошибку, напишите ее пожалуйста

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста подробнее суть задачи, думаю получиться решить все ошибки

Comment: Суть задачи: горизонтальное перемещение кота до правой стенки . Ширину окна и кота знаем,. Я уже понял, что можно все сделать  (продублировать вертикаль через translateX ). Но эта функция полезная, она работает для статичных значений '400' . Как на место 400 всунуть разницу между окном и котом :) ?